# SQL Server datatype to store only time field like 09:10 etc

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to store the office starting time etc in my database.

The time I want to store is like `09:15 AM` or `1:15PM` etc

My question is what is the best way to store it?

For the time being I am using `int` in SQL Server.

And I am storing the data like `0915, 1605, 2305` (maybe I can use some sort of constraints too)

Is there any better and good way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this question for some useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538739/best-way-to-store-time-hhmm-in-a-database

Comment: From SQL Server 2008 you can use [`TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2008 or newer, you can use [TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) Datatype to store only time.

Comment: What is the equivalent of `TIME` for sql server 2005 ?