# How to store time data type in neo4j?

Tags: time, neo4j

I created some user nodes with some value-time:

```
CREATE (u1:User {name:'user 1', pickUpTime:'10:10', dropOffTime:'10:35'})
```

I wonder what is a good way (format) to store time, because when i do this kind of queries

```
MATCH (u:User) RETURN u.name AS name, u.pickUpTime AS pickTime Order by pickTime desc
```

I got this as result

```
name    pickTime
user 3  9:30
user 2  10:20
user 1  10:10
```

And i need to get an ordered result:

```
 name   pickTime
 user 3  9:30
 user 1 10:10
 user 2 10:20
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two notes:

1. You should use a format like HH:mm that means that you need to specify 9:30 as 09:30.
2. Also in the previous case you need to specify "order by pickTime asc" and not desc if you would like to obtain the order you desire

Comment: With Neo4j 2.3. and an index on that field you can also use range search on the field as well as `starts with` to find for instance all `09:` 9 o'clock matches.

Answer (score 2):

Time is a much trickier thing that it first appears, usually because time often refers back to a timezone, a date, or something else.

Many people will store the [epoch time](http://www.epochconverter.com/) that they get from java via `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`.  They'll then convert it to whatever they need later on.

Other people will store [the number of minutes after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538739/best-way-to-store-time-hhmm-in-a-database) if they're just looking for a relative time of day (i.e. 2:30PM)

Another option is to use Java `Date` objects as values.  These are richer and allow you to express a timezone, calendar concepts, etc.

Storing them as strings is definitely a losing proposition for most use cases.  Storing as something like a long integer permits direct comparison, but also requires that you convert something like an epoch time to a string that you really want, like "9:30"

Comment: there is also the timestamp() function in cypher

Comment: @FrobberOfBits thank you, i think storing the number of minutes after midnight is a good option. So i think i will consider it if i want to perform calculation btw times