# Save only time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two time fields in the table i.e. `start_time and end_time` .
When I execute `MyModel.save(start_time: '12:34')`, it gets saved with appending a `date(Sat, 01 Jan 2000 07:25:00 UTC +00:00)`.
I want to save time only. I am using `Rails5`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/538754/297087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we execute, `a = MyModel.save(start_time: '12:34')`, it saves only time in the database. But when we display the value in the console(`a.start_time`), we gets time with date. So we have to retrieve time from it by the following:

```
a.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Data gets correctly saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

Rails will always append date with time even its type is "time".
You can achieve storing only time using sql query.
But i would suggest you to use one of the following options:

1)store time in column of type fixnum or decimal in 24hrs format like "22.44"

2) Store number of seconds in column of type integer & then write a helper method to confirm it into time.

3)Use column type :time and ignore the date whole querying.