# How to get Radtime picker time and store in database sql server 2005 in asp .net

Tags: c#

Coding page

cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", Convert.ToDateTime(tp_StartTime.SelectedTime).ToString("HH:mm"));

Comment: What is the datatype of the column on the database table that you are trying to update with your value?

Comment: i use datetime datatype

Comment: Hi @PradeepaLogu what datatype is startDate? Does changing startDate from datetime to date in your sql server help?

Comment: startDate datatype is datetime sir. my sql server version is 2005. i have  only one  option date time. how can i store time only in database without date

Comment: Check this to store time in sql server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538739/best-way-to-store-time-hhmm-in-a-database

Comment: Why is your SQL version so out of date? It went out of support many years ago. You should plan to upgrade a.s.a.p. newer versions also have a specific `time` data type which would be useful for this.