# SQL: How can i use the Time Function

Tags: sql

I need some help creating a table in SQL. I am trying to add time to a table but without the date, I am still a beginner so I have no idea what I am supposed to do. Is there anyone that can help?

```
CREATE TABLE store( 
                    Store_ID   INT NOT NULL, 
                    Store_Type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
                    Store_Info VARCHAR(100), 
                    Store_Name VARCHAR(100), 
                    Time_open  TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
                    Time_close TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
                    PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID) 
                  );
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Which SQL? Can you tag your DBMS please?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538739/best-way-to-store-time-hhmm-in-a-database

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description clearly recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatype `TIME` in most RDBMS.
MySQL *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=77ffebabaff72e059b4266077795040c)*
SQL-server *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=77ffebabaff72e059b4266077795040c)*
Postgres  *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77ffebabaff72e059b4266077795040c)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE store( 
>                     Store_ID   INT NOT NULL, 
>                     Store_Type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
>                     Store_Info VARCHAR(100), 
>                     Store_Name VARCHAR(100), 
>                     Time_open  TIME  NOT NULL, 
>                     Time_close TIME  NOT NULL, 
>                     PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID) 
>                   );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO store values (1,'type','info','name','09:00','18:00')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM store;
> ```
>
> ```
> Store_ID | Store_Type | Store_Info | Store_Name | Time_open | Time_close
> -------: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------- | :---------
>        1 | type       | info       | name       | 09:00:00  | 18:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77ffebabaff72e059b4266077795040c)*